# Python - ¿Cómo pedir a usuario que ingrese fechas?

Tags: python

Como pedir al usuario que me de una fecha y esa fecha poderla imprimir en pantalla con un formato de dd/mm/año

Comment: Mira por favor como preguntar

Answer (score 1):

Ya que no colocaste el código que has intentado no podemos ayudarte como se debería

Pero te podría dar una idea

```
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    fecha_str = input('\n Ingrese fecha "aaaa/mm/dd"...: ')
    try:
        fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha_str, '%Y/%m/%d').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        print("\n Tu fecha es: ")
        print(str(fecha))
    except ValueError:
        print("\n No ha ingresado una fecha correcta...")
    else:
        break
```

Y da como resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias...

Comment: Lamento no haber formulado bien la pregunta apenas estoy aprendiendo...

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta y si es la correcta solo dar palomita para indicar que esta resuelta =)

Comment: no puedo hacerlo me sale este anuncio:
¡Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente.